# Cannot remove the item in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

Am trying to fetch an API and its working but when I try to delete the last array with a method "**.pop()**" or with "**.slice(0,4**)" it displays: **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.body.data.pop is not a function**

This is a link to the code on codesandox https://d8i7m.csb.app/

I'm making using vue and vue-resource

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <ol>
      <li v-for="blog in blogs" :key="blog.id">{{ blog }}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      blogs: [],
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.$http
      .get("https://covidnigeria.herokuapp.com/api")
      .then(function (data) {
        this.blogs = data.body.data;
        console.log(data.body.data);
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

this is an image of my work

[image: this is an image of my work]

I want to delete the 6th array and only display from 1-5

Am new to using APIs in application.

Comment: I have posted this same question but it was closed without an answer. I guess the previous one wasn't clear. I tried to may this one as clear as I can.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data)`? There doesn't appear to be a property named `body`. Try `data.states.pop()`.

Comment: In my point of view you should try `console.log(typeof this.blogs);` after you assign value for `this.blogs`. I believe that it is not an array.

Comment: If you intend to delete last item of 'states' in the 'data', try this - 

this.blogs.states = this.blogs.states.slice(0, 4);

Comment: sorry, this is not an array but a json object. @phil has answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the actual data coming back from your API. It is **not** an array

```js
{
  "data": {
    "totalSamplesTested": "535733",
    "totalConfirmedCases": 59345,
    "totalActiveCases": 7464,
    "discharged": 50768,
    "death": 1113,
    "states": [/* lots of data here */]
  }
}
```

I suggest you display the data you want by its key

```html
<ol>
  <li>{{ blogs.totalSamplesTested }}</li>
  <li>{{ blogs.totalConfirmedCases}}</li>
  <li>{{ blogs.totalActiveCases}}</li>
  <li>{{ blogs.discharged}}</li>
  <li>{{ blogs.death}}</li>
</ol>
```

If you still want to iterate the data and skip `states`, create a computed property that returns everything with `states` omitted and iterate that

```html
<ol>
  <li v-for="stat in stats" :key="stat.key">
    {{ stat.label }}: {{ stat.dataPoint }}
  </li>
</ol>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  blogs: {} //  an empty object, not an array
}),
computed: {
  stats: ({ blogs }) => {
    const { states, ...stats } = blogs
    return Object.entries(stats).map(([ key, dataPoint ]) => ({
      key,
      dataPoint,
      label: `${key[0].toUpperCase()}${key.slice(1).replace(/[A-Z]/g, " $&")}`
    }))
  }
}
```